# MySQL search affected rows based on stock level

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have the following table:

```
production(rec_ID, item_ID, date, qty)
usage(rec_ID, item_ID, date, qty)
inventory(item_ID, stock)
```

With the following sample data:

```
Production
Rec_ID | item_ID | date | qty
1      | A       | 2016-01-18 | 50
2      | A       | 2016-01-19 | 50
3      | A       | 2016-01-20 | 50

Usage
Rec_ID | item_ID | date | qty
100    | A       | 2016-01-20 | 70

Inventory
item_ID| stock
A      | 80
```

As you can see, anything in production will increase Inventory and anything on Usage will decrease Inventory. Now I have 80 pieces of stock A. I want to search which row have the remaining stock in table production. The rule is: production from earlier date will be used up first.

Usage ID 100 will be taken from Production ID 1 first (70 - 50). Remaining 20 will be taken from Production ID 2. Therefore, remaining stock is: 80 ( 30 from Production ID 2 and 50 from Production ID 3). How can I get the affected rows in Production table based on Inventory stock? I am thinking something like:

```
SELECT * FROM production ORDER BY date DESC
```

loop through the item adding up qty until it reach current stock level. For example:

```
current_Stock = SELECT stock FROM Inventory WHERE item_ID='A'
production_List = SELECT * FROM production WHERE item_ID='A' ORDER BY date DESC

for each production in production_List
    qty_total += production.qty
    (add each production to arraylist or something)
    if qty_total >= current_Stock
        exit for
    end if
next

(process affected rows...)
```

Is there a more elegant way to do it in pure SQL?

Comment: "pure" SQL is not always the best answer for complex business rules like this. You could probably write up a stored procedure to do it, but consider the disadvantages of having this stuff stuck in the database instead of your application code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this query might be a solution

```
    SELECT NULL AS Rec_ID,
       qty,
       NULL AS total,
       `date`
FROM cc
WHERE (@total := 0)
UNION
SELECT Rec_ID, qty, @total := @total + qty AS total, `date`
FROM
  (SELECT *
   FROM Production
   ORDER BY `date` DESC
   WHERE item_ID='A') tmp
WHERE @total <
    (SELECT stock
     FROM Inventory
     WHERE item_ID='A') ;
```

Fiddle for this is http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/95b3a/1